# Replacing Java unicode encodings with actual characters

Tags: java, html, encoding, character

When I make web queries, for accented characters, I get special character encodings back as strings such as "\u00f3" , but I need to replace it with the actual character, like "ó" before making another query.

How would I find these cases without actually looking for each one, one by one?

Comment: Are you talking about JSON data? Because I can't think of any other web technology that uses Java-style Unicode escapes. And any sane JSON library should automatically handle those escapes for you.

Comment: Yep it is JSON! I am new to the JSON format -- would JSOUP do the trick?

Comment: No, JSOUP is a HTML parser, it doesn't do JSON, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're handling [JSON formatted data](http://json.org/).

Use any of the many freely available JSON libraries to handle this (and other parsing issues) for you instead of trying to do it manually.

The [one from JSON.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) is pretty widely used, but there are [surely](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) [others](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) that work [just as well](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20json%20library).

Comment: Read about the JSON format off a simple google search already, and it would have helped if you pointed to a class or even sample code, but still close enough I guess.